# Is it possible to map json with java class with json entities with space?

Tags: java, android, json

I have some json code like this:

```
{
"First name": "David",
"Last name": "Esseiva"
}
```

and I want to map it with my java class. But normally we cannot create properties in java class like this:

```
class Name{
String first name;
String last name;
}
```

If we create like this:

```
class Name{
String first_name;
String last_name;
}
```

Is it possible to let it map together?

So, I want to know what is a possible way to map these together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, Gson is what you are looking for

http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

In your case, you would do something like this

```
Name nameObjectModel = gsonObj.fromJson("JsonStringHere", Name.class)
```

and it will do all the serializing for you :)

Comment: Nope, the problem is that I the name of json and Object properties, not  how to map it... generally, if if want to map java class and json we need to create a class java with the properties name of class match the entities of json, but now u see the json entities is "Last name", there is a space, so how can we create a java properties for it ??

Comment: you use this annotation @SerializedName("last name") Please refer to the Gson API and User guide for more details :)

Answer (score 1):

Try out [Jackson JSON Processor's Data Binding](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDataBinding).